# Golem variations

Tags: the-secret-world

I have been taking part in open world battles with golems recently.

I've done about 30 fights now and I noticed that some take longer than others and some seem to do things at different rates than others. Not meaning to be too broad, what are the variations of open world golem boss fights? Are they all the same, are my experiences of differing ability timings to do with lag and random player damage output or what?

I also noticed that certain golem attacks not occur if the golem moves around after performing the previous ability, is this simply a matter of switching tanks?